# Powershell Compress-Archive files into folders

Tags: powershell, compression

How can I place the result into folders in the archive?
for example:

```
$Compress-Archive -Path .\Client\*.exe, .\Server\*.exe  -DestinationPath ('Build_' + (get-date -Format yyyy.MM.dd) + '.zip')
```

I would like to have a folder Client with it's exe files and a folder Server with it's exe files in the archive. Now all files are directly in the 'root' of the archive.

When compressing an entire folder the folder name is included in  the archive.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this may get you started modified from here :-

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb835e63-0ed5-417b-980b-46d2982f4e0b/add-a-folder-to-an-existing-zip-file-using-powershell-v4-or-lower?forum=winserverpowershell

```
$sources = "c:\client","c:\server"
$destination = "c:\test\" + "multifoler.zip"

function Add-Zip
   {
    param([string]$zipfilename)

    if(-not (test-path($zipfilename)))
    {
        set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
        (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false  
}

$shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)

foreach($file in $input) 
{ 
        $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
        Start-sleep -milliseconds 500
}
}

foreach($source in $sources){
 Get-Item $source | Add-Zip $destination
}
```

Comment: Als long as you zip entire folders this will work, but when using wildcards in the $sources all files come in one file without folders